# Changing the button text color when selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uibutton

I have a custom button and I am setting the different image when it is highlighted. Now, I want to change the color of the text on the button when button is highlighted. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: Where can i add this code ...ViewDidLoad or Action method

Answer (score 3):

**Swift** version:

```
myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also achieve this with storyboards by selecting in the attributes inspector under Button the State Config to Selected or Highlighted and style the button right there - no code needed :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

or

```
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

This works for me.